# Word Addin VBA-C# conversion, InputBox

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word

I'm converting our word tools from VBA to C#. I have a very general question:

There are many built in functions in VBA that do not seem to translate directly to c#. For instance, the DoEvents keyword can only be accessed through the windows form library with application.DoEvents.

The built in pop-up boxes are another example - the one I have not yet managed to figure out.

In VBA:

```
dim s as string
MsgBox("Prompt") //Simple message
s = InputBox("Prompt") //Get user input
```

For now, I have resorted to using windows forms instead - which work out nicely; however, I would like to know if there are any built in pop-ups that mimic the ones in VBA. I did find the MessageBox in the windows forms library but I have not found an InputBox.

Comment: I'm assuming that you want a "Prompt" with an input box. C# does not have anything like that...make an extra form that has the input that you want and then show / hide it when you need user input. In other words you have to build one yourself.

Comment: I was hoping there was something built in. Most of our macros have several pop ups so it has been better for me to combine them all into 1 form anyway. I was just looking for simplicity as our other developers are not as familiar with windows forms. If you're correct, the answer would be "Doesn't exist," which sucks :( I will make an easy to use form so that I can teach them to customize the prompt as that sounds like the best solution.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10181/InputBox-in-C

Comment: @dee You're my hero :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when moving a monster VBA project over to C# as an Excel Add-In. What I found was, like comments above, C# doesn't really have an `inputbox` to get user input. BUT, you can utilize Visual Basic inside the C# program if you reference it in your solution, or just string the libraries together:

```
string inputFromUser = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Prompt", "Title", "Default", -1, -1);
```